# How to load all the custom markers from firebase RTDB into google map in flutter(dart) for other users to see?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, mobile-development

I am trying to load all my markers into Google Map for the other users to see. I'm using Flutter for developing my app in the android studio. The markers are saved in the firebase Realtime Database. There are latitude and longitude and post sections for each marker. The post is a text that displays a msg for other users upon clicking on the marker.
[My firebase RTBD looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zl1ye.jpg)
[and how my markers are represented in the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pARjr.jpg)

The JSON file is like this:

```html
{
  "users" : {
    "SR7Z4qYbFEPXTelucOyTTHoiI433" : {
      "email" : "user1@gmail.com",
      "marker" : {
        "latitude" : 34.16599,
        "longitude" : -118.26079333333334,
        "posts" : "coffee?"
      },
      "phone" : "1111111111",
      "uid" : "SR7Z4qYbFEPXTelucOyTTHoiI433",
      "username" : "user1"
    },
    "UwzHxCPeE9dD1Owq8iZeqDyQ2Ar2" : {
      "email" : "user2@gmail.com",
      "marker" : {
        "latitude" : 34.146993333333334,
        "longitude" : -118.243845,
        "posts" : "library?"
      },
      "phone" : "2222222222",
      "uid" : "UwzHxCPeE9dD1Owq8iZeqDyQ2Ar2",
      "username" : "user2"
    },
    "wyyV5pErxFhaYdSJPVJShZdH6FC3" : {
      "email" : "user3@gmail.com",
      "marker" : {
        "latitude" : 34.05831,
        "longitude" : -117.82177166666666,
        "posts" : "good food?"
      },
      "phone" : "3333333333",
      "uid" : "wyyV5pErxFhaYdSJPVJShZdH6FC3",
      "username" : "user3"
    }
  }
}
```

The output that I print in debugger works, however, the markers are non shown correctly. For example, initially, the marker is in the user2 location and when I create the post again the marker stays there.
by adding:

```
print(key);
print((values['marker'])["latitude"]);
print((values['marker'])["longitude"]);
```

```js
I/flutter ( 6509): SR7Z4qYbFEPXTelucOyTTHoiI433
I/flutter ( 6509): 34.16599
I/flutter ( 6509): -118.26079333333334
I/flutter ( 6509): ------------------------
I/flutter ( 6509): wyyV5pErxFhaYdSJPVJShZdH6FC3
I/flutter ( 6509): 34.05831
I/flutter ( 6509): -117.82177166666666
I/flutter ( 6509): ------------------------
I/flutter ( 6509): UwzHxCPeE9dD1Owq8iZeqDyQ2Ar2
I/flutter ( 6509): 34.146993333333334
I/flutter ( 6509): -118.243845
I/flutter ( 6509): ------------------------
```

This is what I did but for some reasons, the loop is unable to go to the next one!

```js
 Set<Marker> _markers = {};
   void _activeListeners() {
     double latitude;
     double longitude;
     final db = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("users");
     db.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
       Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.value;
       values.forEach((key, values) {
         //print(key);
         //setState(() {
           _markers.add(
             Marker(
                 position: LatLng((values['marker'])["latitude"], (values['marker'])["longitude"]),
                 markerId: MarkerId("Marker_Id"),
                 onTap: () {
                   //   showAlertDialog(context);
                 }),
             ); //_markers.add
         print("------------------------");
           }
         );
       });
    // });
     }
```

Comment: Did you try anything yet? It is much more likely that someone here can help if we see what you've already done to implement the use-case.

Comment: i just updated my post

Comment: Thanks for the code, that's helpful. 1) Can you also show the JSON from `users` of your database (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). 2) If you put a breakpoint on `Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.value;` and run the app in a debugger, does it get to that breakpoint?

Comment: First, thank you for replying! yes the code gets to Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.value;

Comment: That's good news.    I recommend stepping through the code from there, and seeing what is in the `values` map. For example, the top-level keys should be the UIDs and it might be worth checking that. If that is correct, your loop should run once for each user, so that's a next check. If that also looks good, `(values['marker'])["latitude"]` should have the value you're looking for. Step by step this will help you/us pinpoint the line that is not doing what you expect.

Comment: all those steps work as expected. The problem is i think that my markers are not added correctly.

Comment: "not added correctly" is really hard to help with, which is why I'm trying to get to a point of "this line does A, while I expect it to do B". Btw: did you skip calling `setState` on purpose?